# Joining two lists together separated by a comma in Java

Tags: java

I have two String lists (a and b) that I wanna join with a comma after each element. I want the elements of list a to be first. I'm also stuck on Java 7

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
StringUtils.join(a, ", ").join(b, ", ");
```

This works :

```
ArrayList<String> aAndB = new ArrayList<>();
aAndB.addAll(a);
aAndB.addAll(b);
StringUtils.join(aAndB, ", ");
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this?

Comment: What is "string utils"? Are you stuck on Java 7 or something where you can't just do `String.join(",", a)` ?

Comment: `Stream.of(a, b).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))`

Comment: https://www.techiedelight.com/join-two-lists-java/ - not exactly hard to Google

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas yes sorry forgot to mention that I'm stuck on Java 7 unfortunately.

Comment: @JBNizet that's Java 8 right? forgot to mention that I'm stuck on Java 7 unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your being *stuck on Java 7* . . . You realize that Java 8/9/10/11/12 are all backwards compatible, i.e. existing Java 7 code will be compilable/runnable in a Java 8+ environment ?

Comment: @Trunk can't update my Java due to some work requirements

Comment: Companies are very reluctant to transition to a new version of anything until its been run elsewhere for several years.  And it has been my experience that newer JRE's will not always execute older compiled code.  So older code will need a recompile.

Comment: @WJS I have never seen that occur, unless the older code was using doing things it was not supposed to, like using sun.\* or com.sun.\* classes, or using reflection to mess with private fields in Java SE classes.

Comment: @BigMon Did you see my solution?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need `StringUtils` By default `List` `toString()` displays elements in comma separated format.

```
System.out.println (new StringBuilder (aAndB.toString())
                                 .deleteCharAt (aAndB.toString().length ()-1)
                                 .deleteCharAt (0).toString ());
```

The only thing you need to do is delete square brackets

Comment: Nice idea. You could also apply this approach directly to the individual lists so that you can omit the intermediate step of adding all elements to a third list. `String aAndB = (a.toString() +", "+ b.toString()).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");`

Comment: @Eritrean I don't think it's a good idea to replace `[` and `]` directly. List element could also contain these characters.

Comment: That is true. I hadn't thought about it at all.

Comment: Slick solution, Govinda.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the guava library like so:

```java
        String [] a = {"a", "b", "c"};
        String [] b = {"d", "e"};

        //using Guava library
        String [] joined = ObjectArrays.concat(a, b, String.class);
        System.out.println("Joined array : " + Arrays.toString(joined));

        // Output: "Joined array : [a, b, c, d, e]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Java 7, you could write a static method to perform the task.

```java
      List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
      List<String> b = Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f");
      String s = join(",", a, b);
      System.out.println(s);

      List<Integer> aa = Arrays.asList(101, 102, 103);
      List<Integer> bb = Arrays.asList(104, 105, 106);
      String ss = join(":", aa, bb);
      System.out.println(ss);

   }
   public static <T> String join(String delimiter, List<T>... lists) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (List<T> list : lists) {
         for (T item : list) {
            sb.append(delimiter);
            sb.append(item);
         }
      }
      return sb.substring(delimiter.length()).toString();
   }
}
```

This prints.

a,b,c,d,e,f 
 101:102:103:104:105:106

Answer (score 1):

To get short code you could :

```
String res = String.join(",", a) + "," + String.join(",", b);
```

Comment: `String.join` was added in Java 8. OP is on Java 7.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I can do StringUtils.join(a, ", ") + " ," + StringUtils.join(b, ", "); would you go with this option instead?

Comment: @BigMon - StringUtils.join (assuming it's the one from apache commons' lang/lang3 libraries) is functionally the same as String.join. This would be the most readable of the proposed solutions.